# Why does sosex!dlk run forever on Windows 7?

Tags: windbg, sosex

We recently moved from Windows XP to Windows 7 and ever since the move I've found that I can't run the !dlk command from Sosex in WinDbg anymore, it simply runs forever. It used to be a handy way to catch deadlocks in our code.

Did something change in Sosex that I should know about?

We're on Windows 7 64 bit debugging a crash dump from a x86 process that ran on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

In the meantime I can try and work through !syncblk, but !dlk was sooooo nice.

Comment: A new version of sosex is released. Try it here .http://www.stevestechspot.com/BugFixesForSOSEX.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As Rockstart said in a comment, major performance improvements have been made to SOSEX in recent weeks.  Please let us know if you continue to have difficulty with the latest version of SOSEX.  You can also email the address listed in !sosex.help for support.